# Recycler View Adapter looping objects in pairs

Tags: java, android

hello I'm sorry for the ambiguous nature of my question but this is the easiest way I can explain the problem. Okay so I have an adapter which pulls parsed json data from mysql database and places each json object in a cardview and I have a recyclerview where these cardviews are displayed. Each cardview has a button with an onClick method to change color of button when it is clicked. This works fine except that the action performed on the first cardviews button is also performed on the seventh cardview, action of second cardview performed on the eighth cardview and that's how it continues. In a nutshell when button1 in cardview one is clicked, color of button1 in cardview 1,7,13,19,etc changes. That is looping through pairs of 6. Any idea how to resolve this please.

Comment: This is because you have not maintained the state of your the dataset supplied to the adapter, everytime action is performed and you scroll, the recycled view will create the mess.

Comment: I don't understand please elaborate a little. I don't know how to maintain state of dataset

Comment: inside onBindViewHolder you will have to make a check, that if your view is unchecked set default color of button else set your own color. also not once you perform click operation you mark dataset item as checked and also call notifyItemChaged(position)

Comment: here's the button in onBindViewHolder
    holder. button1.setOnclickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
    holder.button1.setTextColor(c getResources().getColor(R.color.color accent));
    }
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by implementing

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position){
return position;
}
```